Mass modify "Send Welcome Email From" setting in customer accounts
I previously had two websites, but now I only need the second website. I decided to copy all settings, CMS pages and blocks etc. to the base website and I am planning on removing the second website.
Currently the problem I have is that all customer accounts that have been created in second website have the setting "Send Welcome Email From" set as the second website and there is no mass modification possibility to that. Any suggestions how to change that setting for all customer accounts?
The "Associate to Website" setting can be mass modified, but that was not sufficient and for example "Forgot password" email still mentions the second website. I can of course change the email template, but just thought if there is a way to mass change this particular "Send Welcome Email From" setting. This setting seems to be responsible for showing the website in at least some of the emails if not in all of them.

The value for the "Send Welcome Email From" field is stored in the table customer_entity in the field store_id.
you can run an sql command to update this field
 UPDATE customer_entity set store_id = 'new value' where store_id = 'old value'

